# has_many through association with existing object / ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Given models

```
class Composition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  has_many :compositions_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :compositions_tags

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text

  has_many :compositions_tags
  has_many :compositions, :through => :compositions_tags

  validates_uniqueness_of :tag, only: [:create, :update], message: "already taken"
end

class CompositionsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :composition
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Now, for example I do

```
Composition.create(content: "Hello").tags.create(text: "#hi")
```

The result would be is a Composition with content "Hello" and a Tag with text "#hi" having created.

Then I create again a Composition.

```
Composition.create(content: "Goodmorning")
```

Now what I don't know and wanted to do is associate that as well to the existing Tag with text "#hi".

How do I do that in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are flexible on the order in which you create your records, you can create the tag and then create the two compositions in one line:

```
Tag.create(text: "#hi").compositions.create([{content: "Goodmorning"},{content: "Hello"}])
```