# has_many :through with existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170183/has-many-through-association-with-existing-object-activerecord) question, but not quite the same.

I have Musician and Instrument models:

```
# musician.rb
class Musician < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :instrument_attributes
  has_many :instrument_choices
  has_many :instruments, through: instrument_choices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :instruments # with some other stuff
end

# instrument.rb
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inverse_instrument_choices, class_name: "InstrumentChoice"
  has_many :musicians, through: :inverse_instrument_choices
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

# instrument_choice.rb
class InstrumentChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :musician
  belongs_to :instrument
  validates_uniqueness_of :musician_id, scope: :instrument_id
```

I have a static list of possible instruments, and the user selects from that list in a select form in the new and edit views. Assume all these instruments have existing records. How do I handle adding new associations between musician and instrument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `InstrumentChoice` either through an association or by creating the record directly:

```
musician.instrument_choices.create(instrument: an_instrument)
# or
InstrumentChoice.create(musician: a_musician, instrument: an_instrument)
```

Since you're not really storing any additional information in `InstrumentChoice` you could use a simple join-table that does not require its own model:

```
class Musician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :instruments
end

class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :musicians
end

musician.instruments << an_instrument
```

To ensure the uniqueness you can add a unique constraint to the join table.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Philipe.  The problem is I do `@musician = Musician.new(params['musicians'])` in my `create` action, so I think it tries to create the associations for me automatically, which isn't what I want since that will try to create new instrument records.  Should I just load the params in piece by piece, and then build the associations as you say?

Comment: So the musician is non-existing when you want to store the instrument? Also, since I see `params['musicians']`, are you trying to create multiple musicians at once?

Comment: sorry, meant musician.  and I need to consider both cases: both creating a musician profile and adding its instruments, and editing a musician profile where i may (or may not) be adding/removing instrument associations.